# If $a^7 = b^7$ then $a = b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show using just the axioms of the integers that if $a^7 = b^7$, then $a=b$? It seems ridiculous but I cannot find the answer using just the axioms of order, equality etc.

Comment: Which axioms? I believe there is no standard axiomatization of integers (unlike, say, Peano for natural numbers).

Comment: Well, commutativity, associativity, distributivity. If $a \neq 0$ and $ab = ac$ then $b=c$. And the natural ordering of integers.

Comment: @Wojowu: Derp. I really need to stop trying to do math before I've had my coffee....

Comment: @Wojowu: I think it is accurate to characterize $\Bbb Z$ as an initial object in the category of commutative unital rings with no zero-divisors, with unit-preserving ring homomorphisms. This makes $\Bbb Z$ unique up to unique isomorphism. I think we can even drop most of those requirements, and just characterize $\Bbb Z$ as an initial object in the category of unital rings with unit-preserving ring homomorphisms. If we consider the subcategory of infinite rings, then we recover the injectivity that I (mistakenly) claimed earlier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that 
$$ a^7 - b^7 = (a-b) \cdot \sum_{i=0}^6 a^{6-i}b^i $$
If the left hand side is zero, the right hand side must also be zero. But the sum is a sum of integers of the same sign.

Comment: But, how can I guarantee that the sum is non-zero?

Comment: If $a^7 = b^7$, $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. A sum of integers with the same sign can only be zero if all summands are (use $a,b > 0 \to a+b > 0$ and induction).

Comment: @Lucas: Try showing that $a^7\ne b^7$ if $a$ and $b$ have different signs (positive, negative, or zero). Then, assume that $a,b$ are nonzero integers of the same sign such that $a^7=b^7,$ and follow martini's outline.

Comment: Generalize to any +ve odd power $2n+1 \ge 3$ (WLOG). The trick is that $2n - i$ and $i$ will have same parity, so that $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}a^{2n-i}b^i \ge 0$, with equality iff $a = b = 0$.